# How to make box align center inside `.flex-col` Tailwindcss?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I want to make this box align to center inside `.flex-col` using tailwind CSS.

[image]

I have tried:

```
<div data-v-bca28ca2="" data-v-925ac5ae="" class="flex justify-center flex-col">
    <a data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 my-2 py-4 text-center border-2 rounded">
        <div data-v-bca28ca2="" class="flex ml-4">
            <label data-v-bca28ca2="" class="fa fa-circle-o"></label> <span data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full">Client Services</span></div>
    </a>
    <a data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 my-2 py-4 text-center border-2 rounded">
        <div data-v-bca28ca2="" class="flex ml-4">
            <label data-v-bca28ca2="" class="fa fa-circle-o"></label> <span data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full">Human Capital</span></div>
    </a>
    <a data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 my-2 py-4 text-center border-2 rounded">
        <div data-v-bca28ca2="" class="flex ml-4">
            <label data-v-bca28ca2="" class="fa fa-circle-o"></label> <span data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full">Media</span></div>
    </a>
    <a data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 my-2 py-4 text-center border-2 rounded">
        <div data-v-bca28ca2="" class="flex ml-4">
            <label data-v-bca28ca2="" class="fa fa-circle-o"></label> <span data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full">Production</span></div>
    </a>
    <a data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 my-2 py-4 text-center border-2 rounded">
        <div data-v-bca28ca2="" class="flex ml-4">
            <label data-v-bca28ca2="" class="fa fa-circle-o"></label> <span data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full">Project Management</span></div>
    </a>
    <a data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 my-2 py-4 text-center border-2 rounded">
        <div data-v-bca28ca2="" class="flex ml-4">
            <label data-v-bca28ca2="" class="fa fa-circle-o"></label> <span data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full">Strategy</span></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

But didn't work, what did I miss?

Comment: To get a proper answer, provide a working code snippet within the question that reproduce the issue, and indent posted code please, so it gets readable.

Comment: Hi @LGSon sorry for my thread :( i'm new in stackoverflow.

Comment: New at Stackoverflow??...you've been a member for more than 2 years, posted more than 20 questions. Still, now you know what to do.

Answer (score 9):

```html
<div class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what this answer is trying to say. Please [edit] and explain.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Add "**items-center**" to your class like this:

```
<div class="flex flex-col items-center">
<a> lorem </a>
<a> lorem </a>
.
.
.
</div>
```

my first contribution on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Please [edit] and explain where to add it and why that will work.

Answer (score 4):

I think this may help! you can use `h-screen` if you want your content in the x, y-axis center.

```html
<div class="flex flex-col">
  <div class="m-auto">
    <h3>1</h3>
    <button>2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use `flex-col` in tailwind, `justify-center` will center the item vertically. so, to center items horizontally, you can use `items-center` instead.

It happened because you changed the default behavior of flexbox which was originally row to col

Answer (score 1):

*The why:*

In Tailwind the `items-center` is not only used to "align items" center from top to bottom for rows as their documentation shows, but it's also used in columns to align items center in the horizontal direction.

The **main** axis is determined by the `flex-direction` properties (`column` or `row` etc.). The **cross axis** which is perpendicular to main is where the items shift. So, if the main axis (in your case) is `column`, then you use the `items-center` to position items in the horizontal direction.

*In summary:*

Your **main** axis determines your flex-direction while `items-center` is used along the **cross** axis which is perpendicular to main.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are just trying to bring the anchor tags to center, but if thats the case then you can simply use text-align center. Please share your code if am missing something.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div data-v-bca28ca2="" data-v-925ac5ae="" class="flex justify-center flex-col">
  <a data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 my-2 py-4 text-center border-2 rounded">
    <div data-v-bca28ca2="" class="flex ml-4"><label data-v-bca28ca2="" class="fa fa-circle-o"></label> <span data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full">Client Services</span></div>
  </a>
  <a data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 my-2 py-4 text-center border-2 rounded">
    <div data-v-bca28ca2="" class="flex ml-4"><label data-v-bca28ca2="" class="fa fa-circle-o"></label> <span data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full">Human Capital</span></div>
  </a>
  <a data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 my-2 py-4 text-center border-2 rounded">
    <div data-v-bca28ca2="" class="flex ml-4"><label data-v-bca28ca2="" class="fa fa-circle-o"></label> <span data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full">Media</span></div>
  </a>
  <a data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 my-2 py-4 text-center border-2 rounded">
    <div data-v-bca28ca2="" class="flex ml-4"><label data-v-bca28ca2="" class="fa fa-circle-o"></label> <span data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full">Production</span></div>
  </a>
  <a data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 my-2 py-4 text-center border-2 rounded">
    <div data-v-bca28ca2="" class="flex ml-4"><label data-v-bca28ca2="" class="fa fa-circle-o"></label> <span data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full">Project Management</span></div>
  </a>
  <a data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4 my-2 py-4 text-center border-2 rounded">
    <div data-v-bca28ca2="" class="flex ml-4"><label data-v-bca28ca2="" class="fa fa-circle-o"></label> <span data-v-bca28ca2="" class="w-full">Strategy</span></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center the container. Use margin left and right and set them to auto.

```
.yourClassName{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```